Can db_datareader query INFORMATION_SCHEMA?
Microsoft documentation says about db_datareader role that:

db_datareader: Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can read all data from all user tables and views. User objects can exist in any schema except sys and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

The last sentence is confusing for me. I think it means that users whose only role is db_datareader cannot query things inside INFORMATION_SCHEMA, but I made a user with only that role for a database and I successfully ran queries like below on that database:
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
Doesn't this contradict that last sentence? What is the correct interpretation of the last sentence?

What that sentence is saying is that you cannot create your own table in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema. I.e., below is not allowed:
CREATE TABLE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.mytable(c1 int)

As for what meta-data that is exposed through these views, we have the same rules as when querying catalog views: you see the objects that you have permissions to use (to phrase it short). Since db_datareader has permissions to select from all tables and views, they see the existence of all tables and views (except where they have deny}.
